# How can I prevent a double submit($.post) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, double

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#enviar").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        //prevent run 2 or more times if the user clicks the button multiple times to send

        $.post(url,{data:data1,data2:data2},function(rp){

        });

    });

});
```

as prevent send 2 times the "post" if the user repeatedly click the button, without disabling the submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a special class (e.g : `submitting`) as a marker to indicate the request is in progress :

```
$("#enviar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var btn = this;
    // check if already present :   
    if ( $(btn).is('.submitting') ){
        return;
    }
    // add it before request :
    $(btn).addClass('submitting');

    $.post(url,{data:data1,data2:data2},function(rp){

    }).always(function(){
        // remove it after completion or failure :
        $(btn).removeClass('submitting');
    });
});
```

Comment: Using data as in your previous answer was better as not requesting DOM for this purpose

Comment: Change this line $(this).removeClass('submitting'); with $("#enviar").removeClass('submitting');

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event:

```
$("#enviar").one("click", function() {
  $.post();
});
```

From the docs:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element

Or if you want to do some extra checking, using on/off:

```
// Set up the initial bind on DOM ready
$("#enviar").on("click", doPost);

function doPost() {
  // Unbind when it is clicked
  $("#enviar").off("click", doPost);
  // Do your post
  $.post(url, {}, function() {
    // You could bind again on success if you want
    $("#enviar").on("click", doPost);
  });
}
```

Comment: What would happen here if pre-submit validation checking fails?

Comment: I don't see any ;) But you're right, you would have to rebind or use on/off